# Tensor operation in Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a tensor of shape (3,?,16). I want to tile each (1,16) sub-tensor 28 times horizontally and vertically so as to end up with a resultant shape of (3,?,28,28.16).
How do I go about doing this?